# Selector for current page?

Tags: html, css

I have set some selector properties for my website (in this case, my "information" link), but I have trouble setting a selector property that'll allow me to set `border-bottom: .15em solid #292929;` and `padding-bottom: .10em;` on my information page. Heres an example for more clarity: On my homepage, the "Information" link will not be underlined, but once I am on the "Information" page, the link will be underlined. Any solutions to make this happen?

Below is the CSS code, and under that is my HTML code. Please note that I am restricting the use of Javascript or any other format other than CSS and HTML for formatting and design purposes. Thanks!

**CSS:**

```
.information {
    color: #292929;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 85px;
    left: 1px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);    
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

.information:hover span {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: .15em solid #292929; 
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}

.information:active span  {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: .15em solid #292929; 
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="selected_works" href="/information"><span>Selected Works</span></a>
```

Comment: You've got to set this server side, how would a CSS sheet know which page it's in?

Comment: If without using javascript, I am afraid the only way is to use different link page for different page.